# onchange заменить значение

Tags: javascript, html

Если написать `this.value.replace(/,/,';');` в строке 
`<input type="text" name="score" value="28.95" onchange="this.value.replace(/,/,';');" class="form-control">` то значение не меняется, но!
Если результат вывести Алертом, то в Алерте результат правильно отображается 
`<input type="text" name="score" value="28.95" onchange="alert(this.value.replace(/,/,';'));" class="form-control">`

Подскажите как правильно сделать? На сколько я понимаю не корректно присваиваю значение. 
 В отдельную функцию не хотелось бы всё это добавлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input type="text" name="score" value="28.95"
  onchange="this.value=this.value.replace(/,/,';');" class="form-control">
```